# Winnovative HTML to PDF Converter - Not saving a dynamic javascript page

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, knockout.js, winnovative

I have tried looking for a solution to this problem on the site, but can't appear to find one. I have limited knowledge about this particular subject, so please excuse my ignorance!

Our website converts HTML to PDF using the Winnovative HTML to PDF converter.

The pages that need to be converted are using KnockoutJS and therefore the HTML code is not in the page source when the page is originally loaded.

I have tried setting a 30 second page delay, but it seems like the converter won't even save our home page, e.g. www.zapkam.com, let alone the pages that I actually need to save, e.g. http://www.zapkam.com/print.htm#/Orders/ZK1019467/Order/

This had previously been working fine on version 11.6.0.0 on a Windows 2008 Server, but since transferring to version 12.5.0.0 on a Windows 2012 Server, it is no longer working.

The fact that it was working before seems to point towards it potentially being a permissions issue as the server is not configured, but I would be very grateful for any insight!!

Comment: Hi William, I will create a small demo of HTML page to PDF. I download the code and making Javascript page to PDF.. it will work.. I will send solutions asap.

Comment: I checked your application used knockout typescript and ko templates. in order to use C# page , Instead of we can use HTML to PDFusing different library. it will convenient for you web application ..

Comment: I had seen that API function to convert PDF was showing undefined.. It means it has not permission to run in server or other issue might be there. instead of I give you solution for PDF you can download and check my below demo application code..

Answer (score 0):

It will done using Javascript with Canvas, 
As I had written code in your Print.html Page..
After successful HTML Rendered we need to call my button "print PDF" find in demo application..

Look into my demo Index page , It will create PDF and write to the client browser..

please check attached application..
[www.maplayout.com/zampak.zip](http://www.maplayout.com/zampak.zip)

Thanks,
Abhishek